# Android - Replacing One interface with other one using rx-kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, rx-kotlin

I have a three layers in my application **app**, **data**, **domain**, i will be getting my result entity for my **app** from **domain** layer , the result entity class will be implementing with some interface **L1**, my need is when the result reaches app layer i need to replace the interface **L1** which is implemented in result entity  to interface **L2**

Example
**Domain**

```
interface L1
```

The above interface will not contain any methods or variables

```
data class Result(val data : Any) : L1
```

**App**

```
interface L2
```

same as like interface L1

```
data class Result(val data : Any) : L2
```

I am not sure whether i can achieve using rxkotlin, i had a rough idea about it like

```
@Binds
abstract fun bindL1WithL2(l2 : L2) : L1
```

Is there is any solution for this ?
Any help

Comment: read about by keyword in kotlin.

Comment: yeah, but delegation is not feasible for this i think so.

Comment: What library is @Binds from? You are just looking for a transform L1 -> L2 -> L1?